# Linux wget utility and it's option -O-

Tags: linux, wget

I am trying to install software on my Ubuntu, and during following the steps I am trying to get knowledge on what the script actually does. So i have this pice of code:

```
wget -q http://some.key.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
```

And my question is about `-O-`. I used `man` to check options, but only one thing i found there is `-O`, which seems to be something that can lead me to this reasoning:

It looks like it is actually using `-` as the argument for storing downloaded data (GPG key), then through pipe it adds it to apt keys. It does not download FILE.

Am I correct, or is there something more behind this construct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the wget man pages:
"If - is used as file, documents will be printed to standard output, disabling link conversion."

You are correct in that nothing is written to a file when -O- is used. Instead, the downloaded contents are written to stdout. So for your script; the key is downloaded, printed to stdout, and then that data is piped into apt keys.